# Escopo de um service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Estou com um problema em um service do `AngularJS`, após uma consulta `REST` usando `RestAngular` com retorno ***401***, preciso conseguir chamar um método do serviço no qual ele está inserido. O problema é que ao chamar o mesmo recebo a mensagem:

> this.retrieveToken is not a function.

Aparentemente o escopo do error handling não é o mesmo do service, e por isso não reconhece o método. Existe um meio de se fazer isso? Meu código atualmente está assim:

```
util.service('Util',[dependencies... {

  this.buscar = function (addr,options) {
    Restangular.setFullResponse(true);
    var result = Restangular.all(addr).getList(options);
    result.then(function(response){ //success },
    function(error){ 

      //O PROBLEMA ACONTECE AQUI
      this.retrieveToken();

    });
  };
  this.retrieveToken = function (){ //code... };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No javascript, quando queremos fazer referência ao própio objeto (this) em qualquer profundidade, usamos uma variável local para guardar a referência para o this. Ex:

```
var self = this;
```

ficando:

```
util.service('Util',[dependencies... {

    var self = this; // visível apenas no escopo do objeto como uma variável local

    this.buscar = function(addr, options) {

        Restangular.setFullResponse(true);

        var result = Restangular.all(addr).getList(options);

        result.then(function(response){ ... }, function(error) { 

            //O PROBLEMA ACONTECE AQUI (não acontece mais)
            self.retrieveToken();

        }); 
    };

    this.retrieveToken = function() { 
        //code... 
    };

}]);
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta! :) Consegui resolver.

Answer (score 1):

O problema aí é o escopo.

O `this` dentro do `then` não se refere ao mesmo `this` que você criou a função, remova-os ou atribua `this` a alguma variável para referenciar o escopo externo.

Veja um exemplo:

```js
angular.module('app', []);
angular.module('app').controller('mainController', function($http) {
  var controller = this;
 
  $http.get('http://www.google.com').then(function(){        
  }, function() {
    controller.teste(); // Chamei aqui porque vai dar erro na requisição
  });
  
  this.teste = function(){
    console.log('ahoy');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="mainController"></div>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta! Deu pra ter uma boa ideia. :)